# Making a Connection in Jedis

Tags: java, redis, jedis, nosql

Whats the use of connect() method in jedis ?
I can insert and fetch key value pairs by just creating an object,even without calling the connect() method on the object.

```
    jedis = new Jedis("localhost", 6379);
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: i am using redis 2.8 ,Jedis 2.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly there is no comments / documentation to the function to be found, which would explain if it’s necessary or not, …

It seems to me that the Jedis client would connect automatically the first time you send a command, not when you initialize the class. However if you want it to be already connected beforehand you can initialize the connection manually with the `connect` method, as well as close it manually with `disconnect`.

Sometimes initializing a connection might take too much time, in this case, if you’d have a pool of `Jedsi`-objects, you want them to be already connected to the server, before other threads can take them from the pool and not leave the connection initialization to the threads themselves.